# How to Add three action items in action bar 'Nativescript'

Tags: angular, nativescript

I want a menu bar icon at left,one label in center and finally another add icon which will open the modal but I am facing an issue that add icon is placed at left over menu bar icon every time.

I tried `android.position`, a `stacklayout` inside but still the same issue

it over writes the left one every time.

Comment: By nature Android doesn't allow you to place ActionItem on the left. It's iOS only feature. You could assign desired icon on `NavigationButton`, that might give you the equivalent Or completely use a [custom layout](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/action-bar#using-a-custom-title-view) on ActionBar which will also allow you to put a label at centre.

Comment: okay but I have to use label instead of navigationButton to acheive it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this sample code for custom action bar with three action item.

Nativescript code:-

```
<ActionBar backgroundColor="#007FA3">
    <GridLayout columns="auto,*,auto" orientation="horizontal" ios:padding="0 10" height="100%" width="100%">
        <Image width="25" height="25" src="~/app/icons/left_wht.png" horizontalAlignment="left"
            verticalAlignment="center" class="action-bar-nav" col="0" tintColor="#ffffff">
        </Image>
        <Label text="PageTitle" fontSize="22" color="white" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center"
            col="1"></Label>
        <Image width="25" height="25" src="~/app/icons/shopping-cart.png" verticalAlignment="center" col="2"
            tintColor="#ffffff" marginRight="15"></Image>
    </GridLayout>
</ActionBar>
```

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQUcG.png)